# Read function are not called in the ExampleNamespace code

Tags: opc-ua, milo, node-opcua

I ran the ExampleNamespace sample. I can browse the node and return all the nodes correctly.
I can run the client read example okay.

But when I run the client to read value of `HelloWorld.Dynamic.Double`, it timeout, and the override read function in ExampleNamespace is not called.

```
// synchronous read request via VariableNode
NodeId nodeId = new NodeId(2, "HellowWorld.Dynamic.Double");

VariableNode node= client.getAddressSpace().createVariableNode(nodeId);

CompletableFuture<DataValue> datavalue = client.readValue(1.0, TimestampsToReturn.Source, nodeId);

DataValue value = datavalue.get();
```

Did I forget to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

At the second line of your code, you set an instance for the `node` variable as `VariableNode` type by making a call via the `client` object, which looks correct.

However, you never use the new `node` variable later. The next line of code still tries to `readValue` through the same `client` object. I can recommend you to replace the `client` with the `node` variable as follows:

```
CompletableFuture<DataValue> datavalue = node.readValue(1.0, TimestampsToReturn.Source, nodeId);
```

A simpler way of making the same read operation might be as follows:

```
    // synchronous read request via VariableNode object (node)
    VariableNode node = client.getAddressSpace().createVariableNode(nodeId);
    DataValue datavalue = node.readValue().get();
```

Comment: Sinan, thanks for the response... I did the way you suggested.. I still have the timeout and the ExampleNamespace server example still did not call the "read" function... Any other suggestion?

Comment: I also noticed that, there is one extra 'w' character at the first line of your code. Would you check it out? 
`NodeId nodeId = new NodeId(2, "HellowWorld.Dynamic.Double");`

This may lead to instantiate the nodeId object with wrong values.